# mschart: does anyone know how to get global max/min?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

i have an ms chart control.

i would like to be able to scale the chart automatically around my dataset. for example, if my minimum data point is 100, i do not want it to start from 0, i want the y value to start maybe from 10 or something like that

1. is there a way to set automatic chart scaling?
2. how would i get the max/min global points of the entire data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to see this post?

[MSChart - Auto Zoom Y Axis on X Axis Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061136/mschart-auto-zoom-y-axis-on-x-axis-zoom)